# Xpath to find offset parent in element

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have an automated Selenium test which uses the following XPath

```
"//tr[td/strong='Riparian 2m Ungrazed - RBS' and td/button[@id='btnDeleteOption_WG']]"
```

Currently, whenever I query this XPath it returns the element I need but also returns another hidden element which is not on screen.

I have compared the two elements and the only difference is the following

```
offsetHeight: 39           offsetHeight: 0
offsetLeft: 8              offsetLeft: 0
offsetParent: td           offsetParent: null
offsetTop: 10              offsetTop: 0
offsetWidth: 179           offsetWidth: 0
```

I need to find the element on the left with the offsetParent of `<td>`.

Can anybody help with an XPath to find this?

Thanks!

Below is the HTML of the element:

```html
<td class="text-center" style="white-space: nowrap;">
  <button id="btnShowItems_WG" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-disabled="!WG_field.optionHasItems" ng-click="WG_field.optionHasItems ? items.visible = !items.visible : false;" title="View Items" disabled="disabled">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>
    </button>
  <button ng-hide="!efsEditRole_RoleAssignedToUser" ng-disabled="false" id="btnAddOptionItem_16_WG" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="appSummaryVm.addItem($index, 'WG'); appSummaryVm.addItemsByOption(WG_field.fieldId, WG_field.tranche, WG_field.optionCode, WG_field.optionTypeId, $index, 'WG');"
    title="Add Item" aria-hidden="false">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </button>
</td>
<td><strong>Riparian 2m Ungrazed - RBS</strong></td>
<td style="width: 10%;">
  <input name="optionQuantityWG_16" type="number" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-valid-required ng-valid-pattern" ng-class="{
                              'form-control input-error' : (existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$dirty &amp;&amp; (
                                                                    existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$error.max
                                                                    || existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$error.min
                                                                    || existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$error.pattern
                                                                    || existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$invalid
                                                                    || existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$error.required
                                                            ))
                            }" ng-change="appSummaryVm.updateOptionTotals(WG_field, 'WG'); appSummaryVm.edit();" ng-model="WG_field.optionQuantity" ng-pattern="/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/" min="" max="" step="0.01" style="text-align: right;" ng-true-value="10.00"
    required="" id="optionWGW0316" ng-disabled="!efsEditRole_RoleAssignedToUser" aria-invalid="false">

  <div class="form-control inline-errorUp ng-hide" ng-show="existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$dirty &amp;&amp; (
                    existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$error.max
                    || existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$error.min
                    || existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$error.pattern
                    || existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$error.required
                    || existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$invalid
                 )" aria-hidden="true">
    <span ng-show="existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$dirty &amp;&amp; existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$error.max" aria-hidden="true" class="ng-hide">
            maximum of 999999999.99
        </span>
    <span ng-show="existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$dirty &amp;&amp; existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$error.min" aria-hidden="true" class="ng-hide">
            cannot be zero or less
        </span>
    <span ng-show="existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$dirty &amp;&amp; (existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$error.pattern || existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$invalid)" ng-hide="existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$error.max || existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$error.min || existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$error.required"
      aria-hidden="false" class="">
            2 decimal digits only
        </span>
    <span ng-show="existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$dirty &amp;&amp; existingOptionsWG.optionQuantityWG_16.$error.required" aria-hidden="true" class="ng-hide">
            required
        </span>
  </div>
</td>
<td class="text-right">6.00
  <!----><span ng-if="WG_field.optionUnitType">/</span>
  <!---->m</td>
<td class="text-right">60.00</td>
<td class="text-right">0.70</td>
<td class="text-right">96.00</td>
<td class="text-center">
  <button ng-hide="!efsEditRole_RoleAssignedToUser" ng-disabled="false" id="btnDeleteOption_WG" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" style="width: 110px;" ng-click="appSummaryVm.showRemovePrompt(WG_field, 'option', 'WG', $event); appSummaryVm.edit();" title="Delete 'Riparian 2m Ungrazed' Option from field 3/003/003/3"
    aria-hidden="false">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> remove option
    </button>
</td>
```

Comment: can you share the html?

Comment: Without the relevant HTML, I'm not sure how you expect us to create a new locator and solve this problem.

Comment: apologies I have added the relevant HTML

Comment: Well, first things first, IDs need to be unique in an HTML document.  Based on the above you could just use `"//button[@id='btnDeleteOption_WG']"` because it's the only ID in that code snippet.  If the IDs are not unique, that's a bug you should get your devs to fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all elements and them filter by visibility. Below is a Java code example, how to get first visible element from list of web elements.

With Java 8:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[td/strong='Riparian 2m Ungrazed - RBS' and td/button[@id='btnDeleteOption_WG']]"));
WebElement element = elements
        .stream()
        .filter(WebElement::isDisplayed)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .get(0);
```

Python:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[td/strong='Riparian 2m Ungrazed - RBS' and td/button[@id='btnDeleteOption_WG']]")
visible_one = list(filter(lambda x: x.is_displayed(), elements))[0]
visible_one.click()
```